# Entity Framework: Creating custom properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties

Consider an implementation of the Entity Framework in a DAL assembly. I am needing to add a custom read-only property to an entity.

**Person Class**, as defined in the DB, contains fields like:

```
PersonID
FirstName
LastName
```

In the above example, I'd like to make a property called FullName. It would be the concatenation of

`FirstName + " " + LastName;`

Can anyone help point out in the `.edmx` file whereabouts to define this new property?
Perhaps it's done within the GUI designer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of the EF, the only way to do this is as a .NET function in your partial class for the entity. This means you can't use the new property in LINQ to entities or ESQL, but it works very well otherwise.

A possible workaround is to do it on the DB server, but the EF would be totally unaware of the relationship between the properties.

In a future version of the EF, [this will be supported in the EDMX](http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2009/01/13/update-on-computed-properties.aspx).